# Has clicking on the wrong link in a "Verify your Google Account contact email address" email changed my account?

Tags: google-account, security

I received the following email to my Gmail account.

[image]

(all the pixellated sections represent the same string)

I checked the email was legitimate (SPF, DKIM and DMARC all pass), and then I stupidly clicked on the Verify Contact Email button before noticing that the myemailaddress@gmail.com had been added "as the contact email address for [my] Google Account myemailaddress**56**@gmail.com" (note the '56' in the second email address)

When I clicked the link, I was asked to log in to the myemailaddress56 account. I didn't do this. The browser in question was obviously already connected to the myemailaddress@gmail.com account.

The email states:

> ignore this email and that address won't be added to your Google Account. Someone may have made a mistake typing their own email address

which is obviously the case - but I haven't quite ignored the email.

Has this affected my myemailaddress@gmail.com account at all?